# I made a simple Calculator and daced some issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-studio-3.0

MainActivity

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import    android.os.Bundle; import android.view.View; 
import    android.widget.Button; import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   Button b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b0,badd,bsub,bmul,bdiv,bdot,bans,bclear,b_bs; TextView  ans;    String a;    int lenght;    double var1,var2;    boolean add,sub,mul,div;    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
   b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
   b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_3);
   b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
   b5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_5);
   b6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_6);
   b7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_7);
   b8=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_8);
   b9=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_9);
   b0=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_0);
   badd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Add);
   bsub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Sub);
   bmul=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Multiply);
   bdiv=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_div);
   bdot=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_dot);
   bans=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_equal);
   bclear=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_Clear);
   ans=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Answer);
   b_bs=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_bs);



   b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
          ans.setText("");
           ans.setText(ans.getText().toString()+"1");

       }
   });

   b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           ans.setText(ans.getText()+ "2");
       }
   });


   b3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           ans.setText(ans.getText()+ "3");
       }
   });


   b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           ans.setText(ans.getText()+ "4");
       }
   });


   b5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           ans.setText(ans.getText()+ "5");
       }
   });


   b6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           ans.setText(ans.getText()+ "6");
       }
   });


   b7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           ans.setText(ans.getText()+ "7");
       }
   });


   b8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           ans.setText(ans.getText()+ "8");
       }
   });


   b9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           ans.setText(ans.getText()+ "9");
       }
   });


   b0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           ans.setText(ans.getText()+ "0");
       }
   });


   bdot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           ans.setText(ans.getText()+ ".");//this is the place where i need help }
   });
   b_bs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {


           String str=ans.getText().toString();
           if (str.length() >1 ) {
               str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
               ans.setText(str);
           }
           else if (str.length() <=1 ) {
               ans.setText("0");
           }


       }
   });


   badd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           var1=Double.parseDouble(ans.getText()+"");
           add=true;
          ans.setText(null);
       }
   });



   bsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           var1=Double.parseDouble(ans.getText()+"");
           sub=true;
           ans.setText(null);
       }
   });

   bmul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           var1=Double.parseDouble(ans.getText()+"");
           mul=true;
           ans.setText(null);
       }
   });

   bdiv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           var1=Double.parseDouble(ans.getText()+"");
           div=true;
           ans.setText(null);
       }
   });

   bans.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

           var2=Double.parseDouble(ans.getText()+"");
           if(add==true){

               ans.setText(var1+var2+"");
               add=false;

           }
           if(sub==true){

               ans.setText(var1-var2+"");
               sub=false;
           }
           if(mul==true){

               ans.setText(var1*var2+"");
               mul=false;
           }
           if(div==true){
               ans.setText(var1/var2+"");
               div=false;
           }


       }
   });
   bclear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {
           ans.setText("0");
        //  a=ans.length();




       }
   });
   } }
```

I have made simple Android Calculator Now I have Some Problems Kindly Solved these

- My dot Button Pressed More Than One Time durring First input number  and its show like 4....5...... i want that its not pressed or show more than 1 time in first time and after i select the operation of addition subtraction  not its will be enable for me ?
- I  want to set a default Value of Calculator  0 And When i press Any button zero will be override ....?

Answer (score 1):

**1 : Show dot only once**
take a `boolean` variable

```
boolean isDotPressed = false;
```

and then when onclick is clicked you just have to check

```
    bdot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {  
           if(!isDotPressed){
           ans.setText(ans.getText()+ ".");//this is the place where i need help 
           isDotPressed = true;  
          }
     }
   });
   b_bs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

            isDotPressed = false;
           String str=ans.getText().toString();
           if (str.length() >1 ) {
               str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);
               ans.setText(str);
           }
           else if (str.length() <=1 ) {
               ans.setText("0");
           }


       }
   });
```

**2 : default value 0**

to set the edit text default value to "0"

put this line in your EditText inside xml file

```
android:hint="0"
```